# adding text to filename before extension

Tags: bash, rename, filenames

I would like to add text to the end of filename but before the extension. Right now I am trying,

`for f in *.shp; do echo $f_poly; done`

the output is,

```
Quercus_acutifolia.shp_poly
Quercus_agrifolia.shp_poly
Quercus_corrugata.shp_poly
Quercus_cortesii.shp_poly
Quercus_costaricensis.shp_poly
Quercus_havardii.shp_poly
Quercus_hemisphaerica.shp_poly
Quercus_kelloggii.shp_poly
Quercus_knoblochii.shp_poly
Quercus_laceyi.shp_poly
```

I want it to be,

```
Quercus_acutifolia_poly.shp
Quercus_agrifolia_poly.shp
Quercus_corrugata_poly.shp
Quercus_cortesii_poly.shp
Quercus_costaricensis_poly.shp
Quercus_havardii_poly.shp
Quercus_hemisphaerica_poly.shp
Quercus_kelloggii_poly.shp
Quercus_knoblochii_poly.shp
Quercus_laceyi_poly.shp
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Using [standard POSIX parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
for f in *.shp; do printf '%s\n' "${f%.shp}_poly.shp"; done
```

Comment: Awesome that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Might be better with an explanation how it works. The Doug answer is pretty easy, on the other hand.

Comment: @SargeBorsch What do you need explained? My answer, the snippet in the question, and Doug's answer are only differ by a few characters, and Doug's answer explains even less than mine so I don't know what it is you want. If you just compare the difference in the two outputs in the question it should be trivially easy to figure out what they do. I can explain why my answer is preferable to Doug's. 1. I use `printf` with a format string instead of the less portable `echo`. 2. I use parameter expansion which is more efficient than calling an external binary (`basename`) for such a simple task.

Comment: Then the command to rename the files would be this:
`for f in *.shp; do mv $f ${f%.shp}_poly.shp; done`

Comment: Is `printf` required here? If not, using it instead of the `echo` makes the answer more confusing than it needs to be. The little gained in portability (`echo` is ubiquitious nowadays) is lost in comprehensibility for novices.

Comment: @Prometheus Here's the [long answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/9537). Short answer, yes printf is better. If I replaced it with echo I couldn't guarantee that it would work correctly on every machine with something named echo.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes there is a tool called "rename" installed.

```
rename 's/\.shp$/_poly.shp/' *shp
```

It might not be portable but it is easy to use.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, great answer!

Answer (score 8):

As the question is for `bash` there is no need for external utilities, since you can use [bash regexps](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html):

```bash
for f in *.shp
do
    mv -v "${f}" "${f%.*}_MYSUFFIX.${f##*.}"
done
```

> <sup>❗️*Warning*: `for f in *.ext` is *not* reliable as it will break on file names containing spaces, quotes or other reserved characters. A failsafe approach would be using something like `find . -iname '*.shp' -exec sh -c 'mv -v "${1}" "${1%.*}_MYSUFFIX.${f##*.}"' _ {} \;`. If you don't need recursive traversal then add `-maxdepth 1`</sup>

Comment: I like this one the most since it works generically for any file extension. Thanks!

Comment: This is the best answer. Short, precise and compliant. No subshells. Works with any extension (`for i in *.{yml,yaml}; do ...`). Nitpicking: 1. Use `f`. `i` is no numerical index. 2. The question is about `echo`, not `mv`.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
for file in *.shp; do echo $(basename $file .shp)_poly.shp; done
```

Comment: Using `basename` is slower and less efficient than letting the shell do the work by itself.  This may be noticeable for very large numbers of files.

Comment: Also, there are missing quotes and `--`s and it fails for filenames that have newline characters before the `.shp`.

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer I can actually work with for my purpose. This is bash help, not code golf. (reading over this.. I realize it may have sounded like I was being sarcastic. More gripping about the other answers on here than yours. Thanks again)

Answer (score 3):

This worked better for me:

`for f in *; do NEW=${f%.webm}_2016.webm; mv ${f} "${NEW}"; done`

Comment: Well this looks a lot like the accepted answer except that you probably want `for f in *.webm`, you forgot to quote the `${f}` and you're missing a `--`.

Comment: The accepted answer doesnt work on OSX, it only prints out the new file names, it doesnt actually rename the files

Comment: Of course, it shows you how to use shell expansions to get the new file name, in response to the question that is also outputing a file name (with `echo`), but not the required one.

Answer (score 1):

If they are in different locations then run :-

```
for i in ` find /root/test/ -name "*.shp" ` ;
do
  mv $i ` echo $i | sed 's/.shp$/_poly.shp/g' ` ;
done
```