# bash - change filename in a loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames

So I have my input directory, output directory and list of files:

```
#!/bin/bash ## shell type
dir_in=('/Users/dossa013/data/inland-data/input/')
dir_out=('/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/data/cmip5/cru/')

files=('/Users/dossa013/data/inland-data/input/*ts*')
```

where the variable "files" contains the following:

```
cld.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013.nc
prec.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013.nc
rh.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013.nc
temp.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013.nc
trange.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013.nc
wetd.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013.nc
```

What I need to do is run a command that requires as arguments an input file and an output file. In my case, the directory where the input files are located is different from the output files directory.

The caveat is: when specifying the output file, I would like to append the word "croppped" between the end of the original filename and the extension.

This loop doesn't work:

```
for f in ${files[@]}; do ## loop over files

echo cdo sellonlatbox "${dir_in}"${f##*/} "${dir_out}"$(printf '%s\n' "${f##*/.nc}_cropped.nc")

done
```

Ideally, the result would be:

```
cdo sellonlatbox /Users/dossa013/data/inland-data/input/prec.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013.nc /Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/data/cmip5/cru/prec.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013_cropped.nc
```

Where is my mistake here?

Comment: Don't single quote `'*'`  That won't expand.  That's your problem.

Comment: Where exactly??

Comment: `files=("/Users/dossa013/data/inland-data/input/"*ts*)`

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: My problem is similar to this one http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56810/adding-text-to-filename-before-extension but the main difference is that I need to add "cropped" between the end of the filename and the extension.

Comment: @thiagoveloso; Note that for the input and output directories you need just scalar variables, no arrays.

Comment: @thiagoveloso as suggested, `dir_in="/Users/dossa013/data/inland-data/input/"`  and `dir_out="/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/data/cmip5/cru/"`.  Furthermore, you need to quote every expansion e.g `"${f##*/}"` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using one of your sample file names (but working on arbitrary file extensions):

```
originalfilename=rh.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013.nc

tmpfn=${originalfilename%.*}
extfn=${originalfilename##*.}
newfilename=${tmpfn}_cropped.${extfn}

printf "%s\n" "${originalfilename}" "${newfilename}"
```

Output:

```
rh.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013.nc
rh.cru_ts3.22.1901.2013_cropped.nc
```

Comment: You should really make a habit to use more quotes just in case files contain spaces or new lines.

Comment: oh really, I hope you are not serious. Quotes are crusial in bash for the above mentioned reasons. `touch "file with spaces"; var="file with spaces"; cat $var && cat "$var"`  Notice the difference. In this case I'm using `cat` but imagine if one used `rm`. This will have very bad side effects.  **Avoid it if unnecessary!** is just a bad advice.

Comment: @val0x00ff; You should be aware that there are no quotes necessary in those *shell assignments*. Adding superflouous quotes makes the shell code even less legible than it typically already is, so better avoid it in **unnecessary** places!

Comment: @val0x00ff; `cat` is a command; its arguments (similar to using other [external] commands) **need** quoting to prevent the well known problems. But this is different from pure shell assignments! - Please read the shell docs to understand that difference. - (And how can *avoidance* of something *unnecessary* be bad advice? - The opposite is true!)

Comment: @Janis, your answer did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `basename` to remove the extension and then add the new extension:

```
 croppedname=$(basename $originalname .nc)_cropped.nc
```

`basename` also removes the directory, so you can prepend your destination directory.

Comment: It worked, thanks, but I would prefer using only bash commands because my real data contains thousands of files and `basename` can be really slow in this case.

Comment: @thiagoveloso Using `basename` is discouraged. You are doing just fine using parameter expansion so keep using that.

Comment: @val0x00ff Please could you explain why `basename` is discouraged?

Comment: @CarlH basename(1) can strip the directory and extension from a path (directory/subdirectory/filename.extension -> filename.extension or filename). A parameter expansion can do it cleaner and *much* faster: "${path##*/}",  "${path%.*}", at the cost of missing corner cases like path=/    For more see:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100?highlight=%28basename%29