# Add text to end of the filename but before extension

Tags: bash, rename

I have several mp3's that i need to add '_p192' before the extension.

I've tried this :

`for f in *.mp3; do printf '%s\n' "${f%.mp3}_p192.mp3"; done`

following this post:

[adding text to filename before extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56810/adding-text-to-filename-before-extension)

But it just prints the file names to stdout without actually renaming the files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer that you looked at was for a question that did not ask for the actual renaming of files on disk, but just to transform the names of the files as reported on the terminal.

This means that you solution will work *if* you use the `mv` command instead of `printf` (which will just print the string to the terminal).

```
for f in *.mp3; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.mp3}_p192.mp3"; done
```

I'd still advise you to run the the `printf` loop first to make sure that the names are transformed in the way that you'd expect.

It is often safe to just insert `echo` in front of the `mv` to see what would have been executed (it may be a good idea to do this when you're dealing with loops over potentially destructive command such as `mv`, `cp` and `rm`):

```
for f in *.mp3; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f%.mp3}_p192.mp3"; done
```

or, with nicer formatting:

```
for f in *.mp3; do
    echo mv -- "$f" "${f%.mp3}_p192.mp3"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [rename command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html). For example to add the text "_p192" before the file extension you can try: `rename -n 's/(.*)\.mp3/$1_p192.mp3/' *.mp3.`

The above command will rename all files with .mp3 extension in the current directory. The command will only print the renamed files to console. To actually rename the files, remove the -n flag.

The 's' modifier indicates substitution. The first part of the substitution is the regular expression for matching text within a file name. The second part is the replacement text. The final argument to the rename command is a glob pattern for indicating which files to rename

Comment: While you are linking to the man page for the command from `util-linux`, it looks like you are referring to the perl `rename`. There are historically [two distinct lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275278/315749) of it.